# Modifying Containable fields required in beforeFind callback?

Tags: php, cakephp, callback, behavior

In my CakePHP 1.2.5 app, I have a `Profile` model that belongsTo a `User` model.  The User model has a `username` field, and when performing a `find()` on the Profile model, I want to always automatically retrieve the value of `User.username` too.  I figure it would make sense to modify my Profile model's `beforeFind()` method to automatically contain the desired field.

Here's what I attempted to do:

```
public function beforeFind($queryData) {
    // determine if the username data was already requested to be included in the return data via 'User.username' or 'User' => array('username').
    $hasUserData  = isset($queryData['contain']) && in_array("User.{$this->User->displayField}", $queryData['contain']);
    $hasUserData |= isset($queryData['contain']['User']) && in_array($this->User->displayField, $queryData['contain']['User']);

    // request the the username data be included if it hasn't already been requested by the calling method
    if (!$hasUserData) {
        $queryData['contain']['User'][] = $this->User->displayField;
    }

    return $queryData;
}
```

I can see that the value of `$queryData['contain']` is properly being updated, but the username data isn't being retrieved.  I looked into the CakePHP core code for the `find()` method, and I found that the `beforeFind()` callback is being called after all Behaviors' callbacks, meaning that Containable already did what it needed to do with the value of `$queryData['contain']` before I was able to modify it.

How can I work around this without hacking the core?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it, so here's my answer in case anyone has the same complication.  Containable fields cannot be specified in beforeFind since all Behaviors' `beforeFind()` methods are called **prior** to the model's `beforeFind()` method.

As such, it was necessary for me to modify the `find()` method directly on the Profile model in order to append my custom containable field.

```
public function find($conditions = null, $fields = array(), $order = null, $recursive = null) {
    $this->contain("{$this->User->alias}.{$this->User->displayField}");
    return parent::find($conditions, $fields, $order, $recursive);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was puzzling over this too, wondering if the beforeFind() modification was "too late". Indeed, it was.

Answer (score 1):

Matt, I believe it's a nice solution. I'm using CakePHP 2.0.4 and I was intending to fetch only User model data.

Just for the record, setting actsAs for User model

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';
    public $belongsTo = array('Role');
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    ...
```

Then I override the find method this way:

```
public function find($conditions = null, $fields = array(), $order = null, $recursive = null) {
    $this->contain();
    return parent::find($conditions, $fields, $order, $recursive);
}
```

Or, if intending to fetch Profile data, for example:

```
public function find($conditions = null, $fields = array(), $order = null, $recursive = null) {
    $this->contain(array('Profile'));
    return parent::find($conditions, $fields, $order, $recursive);
}
```