# CakePHP 2.0.5 Auth and User Model Recursive issue

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

In Cake 2.0.5 when logging in using the Auth component, it would seem Cake is retrieving all related models; and with many associations, logging in takes a long time.

This problem was first identified here in [this ticket](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/31-authcomponent-and-user-model-need-to-set-recursive-to-1) but the "solution" given doesn't mean a lot, and I can't find anything else in the documentation.

> Using the FormAuthenticate class in 2.0 you can subclass and add
>   whatever recursive level you feel is appropriate fairly easily.

Has anyone experienced this, and have a fix?

Below - sample code:

Standard login method:

```
public function login() {
    $this->User->recursive = -1; // does nothing

    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password.');
    }

}
```

And the query cake is producing for my app:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified`, `Band`.`id`, `Band`.`name`, `Band`.`genre`, `Band`.`location`, `Band`.`influences`, `Band`.`founded`, `Band`.`bio`, `Band`.`created`, `Band`.`modified`, `Band`.`status`, `Band`.`website`, `Band`.`email`, `Band`.`contact_number`, `Band`.`user_id`, `Member`.`id`, `Member`.`user_id`, `Member`.`first_name`, `Member`.`last_name`, `Member`.`display_name`, `Member`.`dob`, `Member`.`gender`, `Member`.`bio`, `Member`.`influences`, `Member`.`band_id` FROM `users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `bands` AS `Band` ON (`Band`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `members` AS `Member` ON (`Member`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `User`.`username` = 'admin' AND `User`.`password` = 'dcec839a9258631138974cbccd81219f1d5dfcfa' LIMIT 1
```

As you can see it's retrieving every field, and joining every model. My app only has 2 additional associations, but you can see how this might be an issue with very complex apps.

When really, it should just be the users table. Setting `recursive` appears to do absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *recursive* option for Auth component.

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array('recursive' => -1)
        )
    )
```

or in *beforeFilter* method:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('recursive' => -1));
```

Answer (score 1):

What Mark is suggesting is to extend the FormAuthenticate class, or essentially override it.

Create a new file `app/Controller/Component/Auth/ExtendedFormAuthenticate.php`

This is the basic structure of the code - I've left in the important bit where the recursive level is set in the **_findUser** method:

```
App::uses('FormAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class ExtendedFormAuthenticate extends FormAuthenticate
{
  public function authenicate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
    // foo
  }

  protected function _findUser($username, $password)
  {
    // bar

        $result = ClassRegistry::init($userModel)->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'recursive' => -1
        ));

    // fooBar
  }
}
```

I've created a Gist with the whole lot in: https://gist.github.com/1565672

Oh, almost forgot, you'll need to setup the AuthComponent to use the extended class.

```
public $components = array(
  'Auth'=> array(
    'authenticate' => array(
      'ExtendedForm'
    )
  ),
);
```

Comment: That looks perfect; I'll try it out when I get home. It does seem a bit odd that cake introduced this feature that doesn't seem that useful in the first place, as well as requiring us to extend the class to "fix" it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about using Containable and override find at model?
[Modifying Containable fields required in beforeFind callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591569/modifying-containable-fields-required-in-beforefind-callback)